# Error when attempting to connect to selenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, curl

I am encountering errors when trying to connect to rselenium. The first error I got was the following:

```
library(RSelenium)
rs_driver <- rsDriver()

checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
Error in if (file.access(phantompath, 1) < 0) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202062/i-got-error-like-error-in-if-file-accessphantompath-1-0-argument-is-o) on this error and added two lines of code before to fix this:
`binman::rm_platform("phantomjs")`
`wdman::selenium(retcommand = TRUE)`

```
> library(RSelenium)
> binman::rm_platform("phantomjs")
Removing platform: windows
> wdman::selenium(retcommand = TRUE)
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
Creating directory: C:\Users\MEGANM~1\AppData\Local/binman/binman_phantomjs/windows/2.5.0
Downloading binary: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.5.0-beta2-windows.zip

Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
```

My error I do not understand now is :
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) :
schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

I am on windows and my R version is:

version
_
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
crt            ucrt
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          3.1
year           2023
month          06
day            16
svn rev        84548
language       R
version.string R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
nickname       Beagle Scouts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Schannel fails to receive handshake from the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472724/why-schannel-fails-to-receive-handshake-from-the-server)

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover I don't believe so it seems to be a problem with phantomjs still as it occurs when it is trying to download it. I like your Tanjiro icon btw.